# Monitor if the real-time position is following a route in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, geolocation, gps, gmap.net

I am developing an app that shows the route between origin and destination and the real-time position of the device by subscribing to its PositionChanged event from the Geolocation namespace in C#.

I would like to implement a "monitoring" feature on the real-time position which can detect what section of the original route the device is (city, highway etcetera). I have a List of all different GPS positions along the route corresponding to these positions and I have my monitoring feature as below.

```
//Getting the current GPS position on GeoCoordinte currentGpsForCompare
//pointHighway is a GeoCoordinte List containing all the points along the route that is a highway

 double distanceCompLoop = int.MaxValue;

 if (pointHighway.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < pointHighway.Count(); k++)
            {
                double distanceCompare = currentGpsForCompare.GetDistanceTo(pointHighway.ElementAt(k));
                if (distanceCompare < distanceCompLoop)
                {
                    distanceCompLoop = distanceCompare;
                    actionTB.Text = "HIGHWAY";
                    actionTB.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    actionTB.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                }
            }
        }
.// and the same for city, hilly drive, country roads etcetera
.
.
}
```

I feel that implementing the feature this way is inefficient and consumes more time since it has to execute the loops all the time. This also means that I am forced to have a higher timeout on the GPS sensor so that before a new GPS position is received, I have completed all the monitoring necessary. Is there a more optimized way of doing this?

Comment: Is it not your job to find it out? You can post some real problem on implementing your proposal, but we cannot do your work: it takes time and money.

Comment: Hello, I see that my previous post was conveying the wrong intent.. my question is updated with a bit of implementation now. Any help is appreciated!